# How to configure logback to create log file name having server name

Tags: java, logging, configuration, logback

My java EAR application runs on 2 application servers. Each write the logs locally with log file names. I want to know how to add the unique app server name to the log file name that is being written in each server. This would help me identify the files from each server when I am looking into the log files after downloading them from server and while sending to coworkers for debugging. Currently we have to put them into separate folders as both folders have files with the same names. Thank you.

Following is the snippet from logback.xml that names the file

```
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>logfile.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
  <!-- rollover daily -->
  <fileNamePattern>logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
  <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
    <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 10MB -->
    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
  </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder>
  <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: You can create `<property name="" value="">` elements and reference them with `${name}`.

Comment: Hello Sotirios,Do I need to create the property name="" value ="" entries in the logback.xml or in the app servers environment with different values ? Because I am deploying the same .EAR file on both application servers? Thank you.

Comment: You declare them in the logback.xml. I guess you'll have to hardcode them.

Comment: Even if I hardcode the names, the logback.xml wont know which app server it is running in.

Comment: You can use `${name}` inside `<fileNamePattern>`, where `name` is a system property. So just arrange for each application to be started with a system property that specifies its name.

Comment: Thank you, Will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Hello, I set up an environment variable with value called "jjsystemname" with value "jjcomputername". Then changed the fileNamePattern to <fileNamePattern>logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.${jjsystemname}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>, restarted the system and the file name gets generated as logfile-2013-07-29.jjsystemname_IS_UNDEFINED.0.log    Can you please tell how to start with the application with a system property ? ex. you mean c:\java <java application name> <arg1>  ? where arg1 is jjsystemname

Comment: I am trying to create the log file name as logfile-2013-07-29.jjcomputername.0.log so that on each application server the file name becomes logfile-2013-07-29.appserver1name.0.log and logfile-2013-07-29.appserver2name.0.log respectively

Comment: When running a Java application from the command-line, you can specify system properties with: `java -D<name>=<value> <className> <command-line-arguments>`. For example, `java -Djjsystemname=jjcomputername com.example.foo.Main 1 2 3`.

Comment: Thank you Sotirios & Ciaran the solution we used is as follows:<if condition='com.ss.java.myapp.utils.UtilBundle.getServerNameSpaceBindingsString("environment").equalsIgnoreCase("Development")'><then><appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender"><connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
<driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.db.dev.url:1521/oracleservicename</url><user>oracleDevUserid</user><password>oracleDevPassword</password>
</connectionSource></appender></then></if> for dev environment

Comment: Following for prod environment in same logback.xml file <if condition='com.ss.java.myapp.utils.UtilBundle.getServerNameSpaceBindingsString("environment").equalsIgnoreCase("Production")'><then><appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
<connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource"> <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass><url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.db.prod.url:1521/oracleservicename</url><user>oracleProdUserid</user>
      <password>oracleProdPassword</password>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
  </then>
  </if>

Answer (score 0):

If you use groovy configuration for logback, you can try

```
import java.net.InetAddress
println InetAddress.getLocalHost()
```

This will give you the local server name and IP address.